# Eclipse breakpoint - How to stop automatically disabling after each debug checking

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

First of all, it has driven me crazy for a while.

After each breakpoint stop (i.e. debugging), Eclipse automatically disabled all my breakpoints.

Looks like the behavior was kind of related to 'Trigger point'. I had to check both checkbox 'Enabled' and 'Trigger Point' so that a breakpoint would take effect. After one stop, the 'Trigger Point' was cleared up.

I remember the behavior happened after once I enabled a conditional breakpoint.

Anyone has tips how to fix it?

Eclipse version:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) 
Build id: 20180405-1200